# UI Progress Bar for SignalR Download and Angular Painting

Tags: angularjs, signalr

I am looking to see if I can show a progress bar from the time SignalR is starting to download till the time Angular finishes rendering. However I can measure up to the point controller terminates its execution. Then the Angular Rendering takes its own course of sweet time.

How do we manage to show the progress bar for the Angular's rendition course and dismiss it when the UI is ready for interactions with the users?